# Unable to connect perfecto mobile through eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to test the cloud mobles using perfectomobiles though test case in eclipse for that i added Perfecto mobile add-in to eclipse and while creating a project i given below details

Cloud : mobilecloud.perfectomobile.com, username and password

after created the project we didn't get any MobileCloud views those MobileCloud Recording and MobileCloud Dashboard tabs are empty. i didn't under stand where we need to add mobiles(i am thinking like we are unable to connect to perfectomobile.com)

Then, i tried to connect through code like below

```
MobileDriver driver = new MobileDriver("mobilecloud.perfectomobile.com","username","password");


        try {
         // write your code here
            IMobileDevice device = driver.getDevice("3152168C4EAA1E2A5DE93CF7B89222720E3A62E0");
            device.open();
            IMobileWebDriver webDriver = device.getDOMDriver("google.com");
            webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id=\"lst-ib\"])[1]")).sendKeys("Perfecto Mobile");
            webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@id=\"tsbb\"])[1]")).click();
```

}

But, I am getting exception like below

```
10:40:39.569 [main] ERROR c.p.selenium.util.EclipseConnector - Failed to connect to MobileCloud for Eclipse plugin on host: localhost and port: 3287. Possible reasons are: The code doesn't run in Eclipse or the user doesn't have ECLIPSE role or the MobileCloud recording view is not open. In these cases use the MobileDriver constructor that receives the host, user and password.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.util.EclipseConnector.<init>(EclipseConnector.java:34) ~[pm-selenium-3.5.0.000.jar:na]
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.MobileDriver.initWithEclipseParams(MobileDriver.java:79) [pm-selenium-3.5.0.000.jar:na]
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.MobileDriver.<init>(MobileDriver.java:64) [pm-selenium-3.5.0.000.jar:na]
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.MobileDriver.<init>(MobileDriver.java:60) [pm-selenium-3.5.0.000.jar:na]
    at MobileTest.main(MobileTest.java:42) [bin/:na]
```

Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Perfecto mobile account doesn't have the Eclipse Role (or license) added to it (yes, they have something like this for Eclipse). Contact support to get it added. I faced the same issue earlier.